# Simple Bash Script, Odd output

Tags: bash, macos

I have a simple bash script that pings a list of IP addresses that are stored in a file.  I am having a problem with the output.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Program name: ping-hosts.sh 
date
cat ./ping-hosts.txt |  while read output
do
    ping -c 1 "$output" > /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo -e "$output \t UP" 
    else
    echo -e "$output \t DOWN"
    fi
done
```

The output

```
./ping-hosts.sh 
Thu Jan 27 14:26:39 PST 2022
 0.199.1 DOWN1
 0.199.1 DOWN6
 0.199.1 DOWN5
 0.199.1 DOWN
 0.199.1 DOWN2
 0.199.1 DOWN2
```

My intent is to show the IP address as UP/DOWN as necessary

```
10.199.10.1 UP
10.199.1.6 DOWN
```

Comment: Try `cat -vet ping-hosts.txt` to see if you have weird characters in your file... maybe you didn't save it as plain text.

Comment: When I cat the file, I get...

10.199.169.181^M$
10.199.169.176^M$
10.199.141.235^M$
10.199.17.214^M$
10.199.169.122^M$
10.199.169.172^M$
10.199.169.173^M$

Comment: There seems to be ^M$ characters after each entry.  When I use VI to edit this file, I don't see any of these.

Comment: I deleted the ping-hosts.txt file and recreated it using `touch ping-hosts.txt`.  I added the IP addresses and how things are displaying correctly.

Comment: the `^M` is the windows/dos carriage return character (`od -c` will show them as `\r`); easiest method for removing them: `dos2unix filename` (will remove the `\r` characters and update the file in place); other options (for removing the `\r`) include `tr`, `sed` ... google search should bring up plenty of hits for removing windows/dos line endings

Comment: the `$` char in the output from `cat -vet` is `cat`s way to visually display the `\n` (end-of-line) char. Note that `$` is also used in reg-exps to indicate "end-of-(line,field)". The `^M` are explained well above. Glad you solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

The `ping-hosts.txt` file has stray characters that needed to be removed. Used `cat -vet ping-hosts.txt` to validate.

I deleted the `ping-hosts.txt` file and recreated it using `touch ping-hosts.txt`. I re-added the IP addresses and now things are displaying correctly